# Does the UK have a legal precedent for "inherence" with refunding digital goods (& associated contracts)?

Tags: united-kingdom, intellectual-property, internet, england-and-wales, consumer-protection

For example, if one were to purchase a digitally distributed video game, then a year or two later purchase DLC (or other content reliant on the game to be used), if a refund was obtained on the original purchase of the game itself, would the seller be obliged to also refund the DLC purchased afterwards, given it would otherwise be rendered useless by virtue of the base game no longer being available to the buyer?

Comment: You're unlikely to get a refund requested 14 days after a digital purchase so your scenario doesn't currently make much sense.

You're entitled to cancel and get a refund within 14 days of an online purchase, whether that's goods, services or digital goods or services. (If you've started the service there may be a *pro rata* deduction.)

Comment: The digital purchase is for something currently under development, with a specified release date that was missed.